# Hard pro coding - strange error in IE8

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8, mustache, template-engine

Please help to find an error in library to compile HTML.

Unfortunately it won't work with `<script type="text/template"></script>` for IE.

"Unterminated string constant" appears in IE8 console in line with this code:

```
return new Function("variables", 'variables = [variables], svar = "' + block(template.replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/\n/g, '\\n')) + '"; return svar;');
```

Full code and example of init() attached here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2trv57rk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems IE8 detects the linebreaks as `\r\n` but you didn't escape the `\r`

Escape  `\r` too

Comment: Wow, it looks like adding extra replace / escape .replace(/\r/g, '\\r')) worked for my problem.

I'll be checking it in the nearest future but for now, Dr. Molle - thank you!